# Denormalize values after prediction in R

Tags: r, denormalization

I am not sure whether I am denormalizing data correctly. I have one output variable and several input variables. I am normalizing them using the [RSNNS package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSNNS/index.html). Suppose `x` is an input matrix (`N`x`M`) where each of the `N` rows is an object with `M` features. And `y` is a vector (`N`) with corresponding answers.

```
nx <- normalizeData(x, type='0_1')
```

After that, some of the data are used to make the model and some for prediction. Suppose `pred.ny` are predicted values. These values are normalized.

```
pred.y <- denormalizeData(pred.ny, getNormParameters(nx))
```

Is this correct? How does it work? It's clear for one input it can use the min and max values previously used for normalization. But how does it work if each input was normalized separately, using its own min and max value?

**update**
Here is a toy-example, where '0_1' looks better than 'norm'. 'norm' make huge training error and almost constant prediction.

```
x <- runif(1020, 1, 5000)
y <- sqrt(x)
nx <- normalizeData(x, type='0_1')
ny <- normalizeData(y, type='0_1')
model <- mlp(nx[1:1000], ny[1:1000], size = 1)
plotIterativeError(model)
npy <- predict(model, matrix(nx[1001:1020], ncol=1))
py <- denormalizeData(npy, getNormParameters(ny))
print(cbind(y[1001:1020], py))
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. Aren't you training your neural net using a training set composed of features _and_ outputs? But you only mention `y` in the context of getting predicted values, not in the context of training. I'd expect that the first `r` rows, say, of `x`, and the first `r` rows of `y` would be used for training. With the remainder, `N-r` used for predictions.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm training neural net using input and output variables. Sorry if it wasn't clear. I made some fix in variables names.

Comment: It seems I understand the solution of my problem. I should use y for denormalizeData. I suppose it is good solution. `pred.y <- denormalizeData(pred.ny, getNormParameters(ny))`

Comment: Glad my comment helped you out. I didn't see your comment at the time as I was busy writing an answer: please take a look, although it seems like you're there already!

Comment: Looking at this again, a subtle point is that I think you should be denormalizing using the values of `y` that you used for _training_. It _might_ also be better in my opinion to normalize the `X` values that you are predicting on using the normalization parameters used for `X` in training.

Comment: re the update, I'm not sure why using z-scores doesn't work here. There's nothing very wrong that I can see. Perhaps the model that you're using demands inputs and outputs in the range 0 to 1? This might be an interesting question for cross-validated?

Comment: @TooTone I'm newbie to this area and I do not understand very much. But seems, the neural network trained better when working with values ​​close to [0:1] Perhaps you're right and I'll try to ask this question on cross-validated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things going on here:

1. Training your model, i.e. setting the internal coefficients in the neural network. You use both the inputs and output for this.
2. Using the model, i.e. getting predictions with fixed internal coefficients.

For part 1, you've decided to normalize your data. So the neural net works on normalized data.  So you have trained the neural net

- on the inputs **f<sub>X</sub>(X)** rather than X, where f<sub>X</sub> is the transform you used to the matrix of original inputs to produce the normalized inputs.
- on the outputs **f<sub>y</sub>(y)** rather than y, where f<sub>y</sub> is the transform you applied to the vector of outputs to get the normalized outputs.

In terms of your original inputs and outputs your trained machine now looks like this:

- Apply the normalization function f<sub>X</sub> to inputs to get normalized inputs f<sub>X</sub>(X).
- Run neural net with normalized inputs to produce normalized outputs f<sub>y</sub>(y).
- Apply the denormalization function f<sub>y</sub><sup>-1</sup> to the normalized outputs f<sub>y</sub>(y) to get y.

Note that f<sub>X</sub>(X) and f<sub>y</sub>, and hence f<sub>y</sub><sup>-1</sup>, are defined on the training set.

So in R you might write something like this to get training data and normalize it, the first 100 rows

```
tx <- x[1:100,]
ntx <- normalizeData(tx, type='0_1')
ty <- y[1:100]
nty <- normalizeData(ty, type='0_1')
```

and something like this to denormalize the predicted results

```
pred.y <- denormalizeData(pred.ny, getNormParameters(nty))
                                                       # nty (or ny) not nx here
```

The slight concern I have is that I'd prefer to normalize the features used in prediction using the same transform f<sub>X</sub> that I used for training, but looking at the [RSNNS documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSNNS/RSNNS.pdf) this facility doesn't appear to be present (it would be easy to write it yourself, however). It would probably be OK to normalize the prediction features using the whole X matrix, i.e. including the training data. (I can also see it might be preferable to use the default, normalization to z-score that RSNNS provides rather than the "0_1" choice you have used.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
You may want to say `pred.y <- denormalizeData(pred.ny, getNormParameters(nty))` or am I missing something?
About normalization, yes, to normalize the prediction features I'm use the whole X matrix. I don't really understand why but '0_1' normalizing is better. If I'm use another I got almost constant answer. Please, look at my update message.

Comment: @luckyi thanks, I edited the answer before your comment to replace `ny` with `nty`. Perhaps you were looking at my original answer, and I anticipated your comment? We seem to keep getting our wires crossed! :)